# Embedded Spring Kafka attempting to start Runtime Kafka

Tags: java, junit, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I have a Spring Kafka project, and I have written some unit tests for it.
When I execute the test classes, the project attempts to use the actual Kafka broker, and not the embedded Kafka broker as annotated in my test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka
@DirtiesContext
public class SpringKafkaReceiverTest {...}
```

What I have attempted is checked into gitlab --> https://gitlab.com/mohammad.mnajar/spring-kafka-unit-test

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#embedded-kafka-annotation).

You need to set the `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` property to the embedded kafka's `getBrokersAsString()`.

Comment: Looks like you have it in `test/application.yml`, but it is commented out (although without `spring` prefix...): https://gitlab.com/mohammad.mnajar/spring-kafka-unit-test/blob/master/src/test/resources/application.yml. Client doesn't care where to connect. It is just uses that `bootstrap-server` property from environment. In case of test you need to override it. That's it.

Comment: not sure how it was checked in as commented out. I uncommented the block, and still see the same behavior. The code in repo is updated.

Comment: despite having the bootstrap servers props in my `.yml` file, I explicitly added the prop in the code as  `System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafkaRule.getEmbeddedKafka().getBrokersAsString())`. Still no luck.